# Pod file issues in iOS flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

How to add multiple targets in pod file in flutter?
I created notification extension for cleverTap and I want to use CleverTapSdk in notification service extension?
xCode return with error

**No such module**

I tried to these lines in pod file, the projects runs but fails in archiving.

```
target "CTNotificationServiceExtension" do
  use_frameworks!
  pod "CleverTap-iOS-SDK"
end
```

I tried bridge-header.h
both of the fixes didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite setting in **Target: Share Extension**:

LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = "";
OTHER_LDFLAGS = "";

and make sure you do

```
pod install
```